# How can I call the most precise overload from a generic function?

Tags: generics, swift

[This guy](http://blog.ilovacha.com/2014/06/09/%60diff-swift-c%60-generics-vs-templates/) says that Swift generic methods can be overloaded as a way to specialize them:

```
func testMethod<T: Comparable>(v: T) -> T {
    return v
}
func testMethod(v: Int) -> Int {
    return v * 12345
}
```

So I'm trying to get something somewhat similar. I have made a class to read integers from byte buffers. It notably defines these methods:

```
public func read(type: Int32.Type) -> Int32 {
    return /* implementation detail */
}

public func read<T: IntegerType>(type: T.Type) -> T {
    let bug: T! = nil
    return bug
}

public func readInto<T: IntegerType>(inout into: T) {
    into = read(T.self)
}
```

There are many more `read(type: [U]Int[bits])` methods to overload the `read<T>` method. The generic method is meant as a catch-all to crash my program if I try to read from a type that wasn't covered by the non-generic implementations.

The `readInto` method is a convenience method so that I don't have to repeat the object's type. If I want to read into an `Int32` variable, instead of doing `variable = reader.read(type: Int32.self)`, I can do `reader.read(&variable)`, and since I hate to repeat myself, I feel that this is better.

My problem is that the call from `readInto` systematically goes to the catch-all `read<T>`, even when a more precise overload exists.

Is there any way to get it to call the most precise overload from a generic method?

Comment: I don't think there is - not directly. If you had multiple generic _object types_ with normal functions then you could manually specialize the object type and call that method. - Also, I have a question: how does the generic help here? Since functions _themselves_ are overloadable, why not just use normal nongeneric functions?

Comment: @matt, because I was happy supporting both models (read with a type, and read into a variable), and I hoped that I would not have to implement both manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not solve the general problem, but Swift functions can be overloaded from their return types. For instance:

```
func foo() -> Int16 {
    return 0
}

func foo() -> Int32 {
    return 1
}

let i16: Int16 = foo() // 0
let i32: Int32 = foo() // 1
let i = foo() // compile-time error: ambiguous
```

This effectively means that I don't need a `readInto` method to read into a variable of a given type, I can just assign to it the result of a `read()` call and be done with it, damned be generics.

Comment: Good call. This is exactly where I was trying to lead you with my comment. :)

Comment: It doesn't work when I need to read into a generic type because it can't be sure that a correct overload exists, though.

Comment: But surely in that case you can specify the generic explicitly? I'd need to see the actual code, but that's my first guess. This works fine (my generic has an initializer whose parameter is the placeholder type): `var myG : G<Int16> = G(foo())`

Comment: [Here's an example](http://pastebin.com/YmMSbkZw). This is a (simplified) typical C++ ELF parser structure ported to Swift, except, of course, that it doesn't work. It's more obvious why this one doesn't work than the other one. I guess I'll come up with a different way to structure it.